# Azure Mobile Services authentication doesn't work Internet Explorer Mobile

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I was interested in developing my app on Azure Mobile Services and notice the authentication flow uses iFrame pattern which does not work on Internet Explorer mobile. However, the authentication works fine on Safari mobile. It seems silly to develop an app using a Microsoft service that isn't supported by Microsoft browser. I assume there is a work around but I just can't find it. Can someone point me to a link or explain the solution? I could always fall back to building my own ASP.Net website with true page redirects instead of iframes, but I would rather leverage what Mobile Services offers. Any help is appreciated.

Edit (Response to phillipv):

**Version:**
I was using the starter project that is generated by the Mobile Services portal. It comes with a script reference in the index.html page seen here:

```
<script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.5.min.js'></script>
```

I modified the project slightly by adding a login button at the top, which when clicked calls the login function in the SDK, which was taken directly from the sample code as seen below:

```
client.login("facebook").done(function (results) {
        alert("You are now logged in as: " + results.userId);
    }, function (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err);
    });
```

Perhaps there is some flags i need to pass to the function to force it to use full redirects instead of iframe transport.

**Browser Version:** I'm not sure where to find this, but I'm on Windows Phone 8.1 which has auto updating apps so I assume whichever IE Mobile that is latest.

Comment: What version of the JS SDK are you using and version of IE Mobile?  There are a couple different methods the login process is supposed to pick among and find the appropriate one for the platform.  It shouldn't be using the iframe transport method in this case I believe.

Comment: Version: 1.2.5, Browser: Latest?, I updated the question with more details.

Comment: Ok, I tried this on the emulator for WP 8.1 and it worked fine, let me try on a real device tomorrow and see if I can reproduce this.